# Calculating end position of annotation on plotly bar chart

Tags: python, plotly

I am creating a bar chart using `plotly` which only has two bars, the left bar is always a larger value than the right.

I need to place an arrow pointing downwards above the smaller bar, the head of the arrow should touch the smaller bar and this position is quite easy to compute, however the tail of the arrow needs to extend upwards and stop at the y position of the taller bar and this is proving hard to calculate because the value for some reason is now a negative number and has no relation to the data at all.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
data = {
    "Big Value": 34000,
    "Small Value": 18000,
}

max_value = max(data.values())

    min_value = min(data.values())

    difference = max_value - min_value

    arrow_start_position = max_value - difference

    arrow_end_position = ??

    print(arrow_end_position)

    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Bar(
                x=list(data.keys()), y=list(data.values())
            )
        ]
    )

    fig.add_annotation(
        x=1,
        y=arrow_start_position,
        text=f"{difference}",
        showarrow=True,
        arrowhead=2,
        arrowsize=2,
        arrowwidth=2,
        arrowcolor="#84be54",
        ax=0,
        ay=arrow_end_position,
    )
```

How can I calculate the `arrow_end_position` value accurately? The y coordinate should be the max value (value of the larger bar) but for some unknown reason in order to have the arrow head point down `ay` needs to be negative so now I am unable to use the max value to calculate where the line should stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the layout height and width, because when you resize the screen for the plot the arrow height doesn’t change. Also You need to use negative numbers to make the arrow point downward. I added a num_to_range function source [here](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/python/s/num-to-range/), And after some testing I found a good(enough) ratio this is the code I added

```
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=600
)
def num_to_range(num, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax):
    return outMin + (float(num - inMin) / float(inMax - inMin) * (outMax - outMin))

arrow_end_position = -(num_to_range(difference,0,max_value,0,410))
```

And this is the hole script after my changes

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {
    "Big Value": 34000,
    "Small Value": 18000,
}

max_value = max(data.values())

min_value = min(data.values())

difference = max_value - min_value

arrow_start_position = max_value - difference

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            x=list(data.keys()), y=list(data.values())
        )
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=600
)

def num_to_range(num, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax):
  return outMin + (float(num - inMin) / float(inMax - inMin) * (outMax
                  - outMin))

arrow_end_position = -(num_to_range(difference,0,max_value,0,410))

print(arrow_end_position)

fig.add_annotation(
    x=1,
    y=arrow_start_position,
    text=f"{difference}",
    showarrow=True,
    arrowhead=2,
    arrowsize=2,
    arrowwidth=2,
    arrowcolor="#84be54",
    ax=0,
    ay=arrow_end_position,
)

fig.show()
```

Note: I did change where the arrow_end_position is assigned

Hope this helps!

Comment: You were able to achieve what I was trying to do, I think the scaling of the chart is what caused me issues now I can see your example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to cobble together a solution for this which might prove helpful or a starting point for someone else, I am not entirely happy with it but I have tested it with quite a few different ranges and it seems to render the line correctly along with the annotation at the top of the line.

I achieved this by using three annotations, a shape and a very small arrow placed at the top of the bar and then an annotation placed at the top of the straight line with just the text in it. It feels kind of grubby but it seems to work.

```
fig.add_shape(
        type="line",
        x0=1, x1=1, xref="x",
        y0=min_value, y1=max_value - (max_value * 0.02), yref="y",
        line=dict(color="#84be54", width=2)
    )

    fig.add_annotation(
        x=1,
        y=max_value,
        text=f"{difference}",
        showarrow=False,
        arrowhead=2,
        arrowsize=2,
        arrowwidth=2,
        arrowcolor="#84be54",
        ax=0,
    )

    fig.add_annotation(
        x=1,
        y=min_value,
        text="",
        showarrow=True,
        arrowhead=2,
        arrowsize=2,
        arrowwidth=2,
        arrowcolor="#84be54",
        ax=0,
        ay=-10,
    )
```